# how to get a map between classes and corresponding stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

For a page, I want to have a list mapping all the classes in use on the page to the corresponding source stylesheet. In Chrome dev I can inspect an element and it lists where all the classes are coming from. But I don't want to do it element by element.

This is a step in the right direction: [How to get a list of all loaded CSS classes in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915714/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-loaded-css-classes-in-google-chrome)

However, I cannot get the stylesheet from a class name. Yes, I can get Document.styleSheets and then search each rule.

But Chrome already has the information I need, is there a way to get it?

Comment: It's not exposed. Devtools uses the internal CDP command. You can use it via `Coverage` panel or manually in the `Protocol Monitor` panel: send CSS.startRuleUsageTracking, delete `body` element, immediately undo it, send CSS.stopRuleUsageTracking and save its response to a variable.

Comment: I enabled the Protocol Monitor through Settings.Experiments but I'm not getting right the command send. It seems to need a parameter. Also, not clear how to save the response. you mean x = CSS.stopRuleTracking in the send command area?

Comment: Open the command editor first and choose target "Main", then send the command from this editor. To save the value you'll right-click it in the response panel.

Comment: thanks, I got it, but the info doesn't seem very useful:
    "ruleUsage": [
        {
            "styleSheetId": "style-sheet-16048-263",
            "startOffset": 1716,
            "endOffset": 1757,
            "used": true
        },

Comment: anyway, in the meanwhile I figured out Coverage which helps indeed. I think your answer is good, if you want to post it as a SO Answer.